# What happens if a muggle-born wizard doesn't want to learn magic?

Tags: harry-potter

So let's say you are a muggle-born wizard/witch, but your parents are of the Dursley persuasion and won't allow you to attend a school of magic. Or you don't want to turn your world upside down and join the secret community of magic users.

Is the magical community going to allow an untrained person to exist in the Muggle world with a faint ability to cause magical maladies and just go about their lives?

Comment: When some random stranger buys you a "drink", make sure you do not touch it.

Comment: From what we saw happen with Harry, I am not sure that your parents *can* prevent you from attending a school of magic.

Comment: Personally, at the age of 11, what kid would think 'Nah, Magic isn't cool... I want another Playstation!'

Comment: @AlasdairCM ... Dudley Dursley?

Comment: @NominSim I think Harry was a special case. I doubt Hogwarts, or any other school, would go so out of their way to get a regular magical child to attend, especially if it was against their parents (rather than guardians) wishes.

Comment: @AlasdairCM Well, I suspect a lot of religions would regard any form of "magic" as devil worship. I know most Christian denominations do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I noted in the answer to jurisdiction question, this issue should not be as contradictory as the question implies.

The Wizarding community would presumably inform the refusing wizard about consequences of violating the Statute of Secrecy and other laws about magic and Muggles.

Then, since at that age the wizard presumable can control their magic (not skillfully, but the won't make people blow up by accident), so they will be under a (explained to them beforehand) punishment should they violate the laws.

To be more precise, a " faint ability to cause magical maladies" wizard will do one of the following:

- NOT "cause magical maladies" because he won't use magic
- OR, "cause magical maladies", and be arrested and/or punished as per Wizarding laws, and accident reversal squad or St Mungo's will try and fix what they broke.

Simple as that.

A muggle equivalent would be driving a car. You can have a completely untrained driver behind the wheel. But if they cause an accident, they get punished, and an extra for driving without a license.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, failing to learn how to control one's magical powers is a dangerous proposition at best (due to accidental magical) and one that can potentially result in the Witch or Wizard dying a horrible death.

It seems likely that even if a wizard doesn't *want* to learn magic, some basic instruction would be given.

> **NEWT:** *I met one in Sudan three months ago. There used to be more of them but they still exist. Before wizards went underground, when we
> were still being hunted by Muggles, **young wizards and witches
> sometimes tried to suppress their magic to avoid persecution. Instead
> of learning to harness or to control their powers, they developed what
> was called an Obscurus.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_(film))</sup></sub>

Comment: Now that FB is out I can see why you'd reference Obscuruses (for want of a better word). But the Obscurus *cannot* control their magic. I'm not sure the Muggle-wizard in the question is in the same category. Both are "bottling up" their magic. But a modern, grown-up magical person, not under threat of the same sort of persecution, wouldn't necessarily become an Obscurus. They might control their magic so that it doesn't burst out of them like it did when they were children. They might be at peace with their magic but just choose not to use it, at least not in public.

Comment: Which would mean that they could stay hidden in the Muggle world but not necessarily develop an Obscurus. For instance, they might 'release' some of their magic when alone, thus not breaking the Statute of Secrecy. They might use their magic sometimes but not want to be a part of the magical world.