# Are You Forced To Go To Hogwarts If You Don't Want To?

Tags: harry-potter

I was reading *The Sorcerer's Stone* when I noticed that Hagrid was very hard on the Dursley's for not telling Harry about Hogwarts, which is fair enough. However, this made me think. What if a student or a family who considered everything didn't want their child to come, similarly to how Mr. and Mrs. Durlsey said they didn't want Harry associated with magic.

Obviously, the Dursleys are a bit of a special case because the way they treat Harry is horrendous, but what if an actual decent family said something similar?

What if a parent wanted to put a "stop" to it as well? Would it be treated similarly? What if a student didn't want to go? Would they (the child) still be forced to go to Hogwarts, even if they didn't want to attend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would happen if someone rejected their Hogwarts Invitation Letter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161314/what-would-happen-if-someone-rejected-their-hogwarts-invitation-letter), see also [What if the parents of a Muggle-born witch or wizard refuse to let them attend Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123857/98028)